# Is it possible to change the \cite command in the following way?

Tags: macros, citing

I know this does not follow very good citation guidelines, but I want to change the cite command so that in addition to whatever the current bib file dictates, it will also print in the name of the title of the paper. So, for example,

```
    \cite{smith-86}
```

will lead to

```
    (Smith, 1986; Introduction to Linear Algebra)
```

Is that possible to do? I want the title name to be pulled out of the "title" field in the .bib file.

EDIT: I want it to be done transparently, so I can still just use the regular \cite command, after changing whatever is needed in the preamble.

Comment: Are you using any package to manage your bibliography?

Comment: Yes, I am using apacite, but I would like it to be generic, if possible? (not dependent on package.)  Meaning, it will always be Original text; title of paper, where original text is a number, a name or whatever.

Comment: Though, maybe I can start with something simple for a specific package, and then try to understand how to do it more generally.

Comment: Citation commands are usually much more complex than they look (and usually do a lot more than it looks like too).  I don't think a generic solution that works with `apacite` and with (say) `biblatex` is going to be possible.  With `biblatex` it is pretty easy to create 'poor man' equivalents of its true citation commands, but they are a very pale reflection of what the real commands do.

Comment: thanks. let me ask a different question -- where does the string that appears in citation (Smith, 1986, etc.) actually appears? I can't find it in the .bbl file.